# HTML MYSQL PHP Umlauts

Tags: php, mysql

I have small musician database , but trouble with umlauts.
Trying to create google charts from data.
This is I've done.

```
CREATE TABLE `musicians` (
`m_id` INT(15) NOT NULL,
`surname` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`firstname` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`fullname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`dob` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`nationality` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `musicians` (`m_id`, `surname`, `firstname`,`nationality`) VALUES
(1, 'Svenson', 'Sven','Sweden'),
(2, 'Johnson', 'John', 'England'),
(3, 'Jääskeläinen', 'Jaske','Finland');
```

website outputs  for name with umlauts are with question marks.
The main problem are with google charts - names with ulmauts are returning empty lines.
What I am doing wrong.

utf8_unicode_ci - no changes
utf8_bin -no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove your `<meta charset="UTF-8">` or equivalent from your browser or...

Before you make any `->query()`, have this `$db->set_charset('utf8');`